# Как установить django 1.3 на сервер с nginx

Tags: python, linux, django, ubuntu, gunicorn

Есть django проект на версии 1.3. Я знаю что версия устарела на лет 7. Но ее срочно нужно поставить на сервер ubuntu. Сам код работает, но запускать его и хостить несколько лет на manage.py runserver вообще нельзя. Тк с nohup происходит ошибка, а без - при закрытии ssh подключения процесс сразу завершается. Подскажите как настроить для него gunicorn. По гайдам можно было бы сделать, но они для новых версий. В любом случае нужен wsgi.py. А в этой версии его просто нету. И как нему его присоединить?

Тому кто поможет - кину косарь на карту. Очень срочно

Answer (score 1):

Документация 1.3 осталась в PDF https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django/1.3.X/django.pdf

Страница 361

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое, надеюсь поможет